# xquery- how to count number of occurrences of a string in another string + 1st and last occ. of this string

Tags: xquery

I am trying to extract some names from a XHTML document--

now I have figured out how to extract all these names in one piece of XQuery code--

For example--

```
<div class="names">
    <b>Names</b>
    <a href="http://name1.com">A B.C D</a>
    <a href="http://name1.com">E F G</a>
    <a href="http://name1.com">H I</a>
</div>
```

I want to extract first/middle/last names, I understand how to use some of the string functions-- what I would like to know first, is the number of times a space occurs in one of the names above, and also the positions of first and last occurence of space. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One of many solutions:

```
let $doc :=
  <div class="names">
    <b>Names</b>
    <a href="http://name1.com">A B.C D</a>
    <a href="http://name1.com">E F G</a>
    <a href="http://name1.com">H I</a>
  </div>
for $a in $doc//a
return
  let $text := $a/text()
  let $spaces := index-of(string-to-codepoints($a), 32)
  return <result text="{ $text }" spaces="{ count($spaces) }"
    first="{ $spaces[1] }" last="{ $spaces[last()] }"/>
```

However, it may be easier to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Regular_Expressions) instead of working with character positions.

Comment: i have one more query-- how do i get the text in the middle(ie surrounded by 'first' and 'last')-- do i use something like { $spaces[gt1 and lelast()] }-that doesnt look right ?? Or can i use a loop over the different pieces obtained by splitting the text(by spaces??  kindly help me out here :)